# What's standing in the way of migrating a Google Cloud Endpoints API to another hosting provider?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

In other words, what part of Google Cloud Endpoints is not in the SDK?

I've seen several people saying that simply running their application elsewhere doesn't work. For exaple, see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/appscale_community/endpoints/appscale_community/BFagV00RUcU/taaAoV5mxNEJ

What part of Google Cloud Endpoints is not in the SDK? Are there any initiatives going to try to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

Endpoints has two components. The first is the SDK, and the second is the API proxy. In theory, both could work on other platforms, but the reality is that you would need to really understand the finer details of the interaction between the two to execute it. You could also in theory try to use the dev server servlets to run on other platforms. I make no guarantees about the robustness of either solution.